# admob swap between banner & interstitial

Tags: lua, admob, coronasdk

how can you swap between a admob banner and interstitial?
if i load the banner on my first scene and hide it when i go to my next scene and want to load a interstitial ad it shows me a banner. and if i don't  load the banner and only the "interstitial ad scene" it loads the interstitial ad

Banner scene:

```
local provider = "admob"
local appID = "ca-app-pub-****"
local ads = require "ads"

local screenGroup = self.view
local statusText = display.newText( "", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 22 )
statusText:setTextColor( 255 )
statusText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
statusText.x, statusText.y = display.contentWidth * 0.5, 160

local showAd
local function adListener( event )
    local msg = event.response
    print("Message received from the ads library: ", msg)
    if event.isError then
        statusText:setTextColor( 255, 0, 0 )
        statusText.text = "Error Loading Ad"
        statusText.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
        local screenGroup = self.view
        showAd( "banner" )
    else
    end
end

if appID then
    ads.init( provider, appID, adListener )
end

local sysModel = system.getInfo("model")
local sysEnv = system.getInfo("environment")

local screenGroup = self.view
showAd = function( adType )
    local screenGroup = self.view
    local adX, adY = display.screenOriginX, 400
    statusText.text = ""
    ads.show( adType, { x=adX, y=adY } )
end

if sysEnv == "simulator" then
else
local screenGroup = self.view
    ads.show( "banner", { x=display.screenOriginX, y=400 } )
end
```

interstitial scene:

```
local provider = "admob"
local appID = "ca-app-pub-***"
local ads = require "ads"

local screenGroup = self.view
local statusText = display.newText( "", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 22 )
statusText:setTextColor( 255 )
statusText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
statusText.x, statusText.y = display.contentWidth * 0.5, 160

local showAd

-- Set up ad listener.
local function adListener( event )
    local msg = event.response
    print("Message received from the ads library: ", msg)
    if event.isError then
        statusText:setTextColor( 255, 0, 0 )
        statusText.text = "Error Loading Ad"
        statusText.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
        local screenGroup = self.view
        showAd( "banner" )
    else
    end
end

if appID then
    ads.init( provider, appID, adListener )
end

showAd = function( adType )
    local screenGroup = self.view
    local adX, adY = display.screenOriginX, display.screenOriginY
    statusText.text = ""
    ads.show( adType, { x=adX, y=adY } )
end

-- if on simulator, let user know they must build for device
if sysEnv == "simulator" then

else
local screenGroup = self.view
    ads.show( "interstitial", { x=0, y=0 } )
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this current thread interesting:  http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/37839-admob-integrate-both-banner-and-interstitual-issue/

I guess AdMob recently switched to having to specify a different ad for both interstitial and banner (whereas before you could use a single ad id).  For some reason Corona SDK only will initialize the first app id to a specific provider.  So if you wanted to use both banner and interstitial currently you'd have to use two different providers.

I worked with another developer to try many things to clear the ad module but nothing worked.  So for my app I just decided to only do interstitial since I didn't want to sign-up for another ad provider just yet.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you would declare a separate Ad object for interstitial (this is how you would do it for Android integration, I imagine it would be similar for iOS), and configure that on the server to only server Interstitial ads.

Answer (score 0):

Here a full example with source code to download showing both.

http://www.ahotbrew.com/android-studio-admob-banner-and-interstitial-tutorial/